# Nfl history - Pre 1950's

Tags: rules, american-football, history, nfl

I'm an old guy. I seem to remember a day (40s or 50s) where a NFL runner was tackled and would be allowed to get up and continue to run. This was before the runner was considered down if his knee touched the ground. Doing a search on google, I couldn't find such a rule change. Am I dreaming?